# Namespace has no exported member

Tags: typescript

When I write this in TypeScript, I get an error saying `Namespace Bar has no exported member Qux`. Why is that and how do I fix it?

```js
class Foo {}

namespace Bar
{
    export const Qux = Foo;
}

let a: Bar.Qux;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are exporting a constant, not a type. You can do this `let a = new Bar.Foo()`, and `a` will be of type Foo.

If you want to export both a type and a constant:

```
namespace Bar
{
    export const Qux = Foo;
    export type Qux = Foo;
}
```

Then you can have:

```
let a: Bar.Qux = new Bar.Qux();
```

TypeScript will determine, based on context, if you are using the type definition or the constant.

Answer (score 0):

The `Qux` in your implementation is a variable rather than a type.
Therefore, the code below is valid:

```
class Foo {}

namespace Bar {
    export const Qux = Foo;
}

let a = Bar.Qux;
```

If you like to use `Qux` as an `interface` or extended `class`, you can do:

```
class Foo {}

namespace Bar {
    export class Qux extends Foo {}
}

let a = new Bar.Qux();
```

Does this solve your problem?